# i have add dynamic row using jquery now i want to add those column

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have add dynamic row using jquery now i want to add those column of the row. Down below is my code i am not able to add the column that is created dynamically.the first textbox is calculated and answer is displayed in grandtotal textbox but the rest textbox cannot be calculated.

```
        <tbody>
            <tr class="data-contact-person">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="a" class="form-control a" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="b" class="form-control b" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="c" class="form-control c" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="d" class="form-control d" />
                </td>

                <td>
                    <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Grand-Total</td>
                <td>
                    <input data-val="true" id="grdtol1" name="grdtol1" value="" class="form-control text-box single-line" type="text">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input data-val="true" id="grdtol" name="grdtol2" value="" class="form-control text-box single-line" type="text">                      
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".classAdd", function () { //
        var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;
        var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person">' +'<td><input type="text" name="a' + rowCount + '" class="form-control a" /></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="b' + rowCount + '" class="form-control b" /></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="c' + rowCount + '" class="form-control c" /></td>' +
             '<td><input type="text" name="d' + rowCount + '" class="form-control d" /></td>' +

            '<td><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>' +
            '<button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +
            '</tr>';
        $('#maintable').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Main table class
    });
});
$(document).on("click", ".deleteContact", function () {
   $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // closest used to remove the respective 'tr' in which I have my controls
});

$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("input").change(function () {
        var grdtol1 = 0;

        $("input[name=c]").each(function () {
            grdtol1 = grdtol1 +parseInt( $(this).val());

        })

        $("input[name=grdtol1]").val(grdtol1);
    });
})
```

Comment: What does `asp.net` have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

First, a piece of advice, don't create multiple `$(document).ready()` functions in the same javascript file, you just need one.

You haven't post your html code, so I'm guessing here, but I suppose you initially have row with the inputs and you also have an input with `name="grdtol1"` where you want to calculate the sum of the values of the column, and it has to refresh when you change the value in any of the inputs.

According to that, I see this problems...

1. You need to use event delegation for the input onchange event (like you do for the `.deleteContact` button). You're associating the event directly, so it only applies to the elements that are in the DOM when the page loads, and not for the rows you add dinamically. You can associate the event to the table and delegate it to the input, for example.
2. Inside of the event, you're selecting `$("input[name=c]")`, but according to the previous code, your inputs will have `name="c' + rowCount + '"`. You chould use the class to select them.
3. If you delete one row, you should also recalculate the sum, because the input of that row will disappear.

Putting all together...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on("click",".classAdd",function() {

        var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;

        var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person">' +'<td><input type="text" name="a' + rowCount + '" class="form-control a" /></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="b' + rowCount + '" class="form-control b" /></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="c' + rowCount + '" class="form-control c" /></td>' +
             '<td><input type="text" name="d' + rowCount + '" class="form-control d" /></td>' +

            '<td><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>' +
            '<button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +
            '</tr>';

        $('#maintable').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Main table class
    });

    function calculateGrandtotal() {

        var grdtol1 = 0;

        $('input.c').each(function() {
            grdtol1 += parseInt($(this).val());
        })

        $("input[name=grdtol1]").val(grdtol1);
    }

    $('#maintable').on('click','.deleteContact',function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        calculateGrandtotal()
    })
    .on('change','input.c',function() {
        calculateGrandtotal()
    });

});
```

I hope it helps